# Algolia Multiple Keyword Search

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I was able to use do a basic search, but in the documentation, I was not able to find any docs for users to search with multiple pramateres.
The database structure is:

```
[{
    "productName": "Product A",
    "productSalesPrice": "3.9900",
    "productUPC": "UPC123",
    "storeId": "storeA",
    "objectID": "obj1",
  },{
    "productName": "Product B",
    "productSalesPrice": "3.9900",
    "productUPC": "UPC123",
    "storeId": "storeA",
    "objectID": "obj1",
  },{
    "productName": "Product A",
    "productSalesPrice": "3.9900",
    "productUPC": "UPC123",
    "storeId": "storeB",
    "objectID": "obj1",
  },{
    "productName": "Product C",
    "productSalesPrice": "3.9900",
    "productUPC": "UPC123",
    "storeId": "storeB",
    "objectID": "obj1",
  }]
```

I want to get **Product A** from **StoreB**.

I used the following code:

```
index.search({
            query: 'Product A',
            attributesToRetrieve: ['productName', 'productUPC'],
            page: 0,
            hitsPerPage: 10,
        },
        function searchDone(err, content) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(content.hits.length);
            console.log(content.hits);
        }
    );
```

I don't know how to query with store Id as well.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add a facet on storeId and add a filter on `storeId:storeB`?

see: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/

Comment: doesn't it filter on the client end.
Like it will fetch 1000 results from the Algolia and filter on the mobile to 50.
So won't I be charged for the 1000 results (read query) rather than the 50 actual results.

Comment: No faceting is done on the server side. If you add the filter you'll only retrieve results that matches the filter.